# Why in the megila when we mention Shushan early on its always with a pasach, shuSHAN but at the end it switches to a kumets, shushon

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, haman

See in the 8th perek it's always a kumets (shuson) but in perek 1 it's always shushan. Any significance in that?

Comment: wow, I think that must be the rule. I will go through and check but if so that's a great hack for leining. I did not know that